# Locating changing xpaths with regular expressions in Python Selenium (v3.141.0)

Tags: selenium, xpath

Being new to Selenium, I am trying to extract some text value out of table in a search result webpage. Depending on the search query, the webpage always has the same structure, but the `xpath` of the element I want to extract the data from can change over time.

The possible `xpaths` look like this:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]
```

Since the element does not have `@id`, I am stuck with `xpaths` I guess.
I looked at the `.contains` function but it does not work.
Is there a way to use `regex` in my command below:

```
myText = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[.]/table/tbody/tr([.])?/td[3]"))).text
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML?

Comment: do you want all **td[3]** text or specific?

Comment: all `td[3]` would be fine. I can figure it out after I think

Comment: Have you tried with `//form/div[2]//table/tbody/tr/td[3]`? and not sure why can't you use `conatins`?

Comment: @supputuri This does the trick, thanks ! What I understand about `contains` is that it looks at the `text` or `@id` values (I am a begginer...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you can use to get all the td[3] elements.

```
//form/div[2]//table/tbody/tr/td[3]
```

Comment: Where do you want to use `contains`? Can you please share the html of the td and the part of the attribute value/text you want to check with contains.